# Catch exception, validate input or both?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, validation

I'm working on obtaining RSS feeds like so:

```
SyndicationFeed rss = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create(textBox1.Text));
```

`XmlReader.Create()` in this case can throw up to 4 exceptions related to things like the parameter being null, 404 error, etc.

Should I try to validate the Uri (make sure it's not null, 404, correct doctype, etc) before I call that line or should I just handle the exceptions?  I know I've read numerous times on SO that exceptions should be used for truly exceptional circumstances and I agree this doesn't seem to meet that prerequisite but it seems easier to just handle the exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Text` property of a checkbox is never null, so you can skip that one. Check manually all the cases that are simple and not related to the process like string being empty and Url being correct and leave more obscure XML-specific stuff to the validation inside `Create` method. So the answer is to combine both.

Also, let me once again refer to a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) by Eric Lippert about exceptions. In your case both vexing and exogenous exceptions can happen, so you should probably catch them. But make sure that boneheaded ones don't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Since the reader and syndication feed interpreter will validate the input, there is really no need to duplicate that effort. This is especially true, since—to do so properly—you would have to accept or reject exactly the same documents. This would be a crazy duplication of code.

I recommend just handling the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking forward to seeing what other people say here, but it seems to me that you should do the type of verifications that you know you can do accurately: check for null URI, check for a completely empty URI, etc. Beyond that, let the Create call handle the verification and you catch the exceptions. I'm guessing that the writers of that function know how to validate it more thoroughly than you do (no offense intended!).

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not a best-practice guru, I do believe exceptions should be exceptions (yes...) It's not only a philosophical thing, it's also a practical thing. Exception handling has, most of the time, a performance cost higher than checking for the exception causes.

Should I want to be philosophical, I would say "If there is nothing you can do about the problem, don't try to handle it." For example, if you want to write something in a file, checking for file exist, file permissions, etc can be troublesome, and you can't do much about it if, for example, you can't access the network drive. If you catch the exception saying "Verify if the file exists and that you have the proper permissions.", you save yourself a lot of trouble.